# Running systemd as user?

Tags: 16.04, services, systemd

I want to run systemd copy for my user to orchestrate daemon workers.
I've enabled lingering for my user:

```
$ sudo loginctl enable-linger dmitry
```

After it I'm trying to run basic systemctl command and I run into this error:

```
$ systemctl --user show-environment
Failed to get environment: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1

$ sudo systemctl --user show-environment
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `sudo systemctl --user`? Also, did you restart after enabling linger?

Comment: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`. No, I didn't restart. Can I do it without system restart?

Comment: Either you'll have to login as that user once or restart to have their session automatically started, AFAIK.

Comment: New ssh sessions with this user couldn't help.  And I don't want to restart the server: it's orchestrated by Ansible,  and I can't restart in the middle of playbook.